# Isomorphism between sets in affine spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I want to show this: The conic $V(y^2- x)$ (that is, the zero set of the polynomial $y^2-x$ over a field $k$) is isomorphic to the open set $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\}$, where $\mathbb{A}^1=k$.

I think that the question is wrong, and it should  be $\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\}=V(xy-1)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$. Is my thinking correct? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It should actually be $V(y^-x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$. Hint: think of the function $f(y)=y^2$

Comment: I meant that the question i think is wrong..the set has to be V(xy-1) not the one V(y^2-x)...am i correct?...and could you also kindly give the answer

Comment: I have not got your answer....f(y)=?

Comment: The question is wrong. $V(y^2 - x) \cong \mathbb A^1$ and $V(xy - 1) \cong \mathbb A^1 - \{0\}$, but $\mathbb A^1 \not \cong \mathbb A^1 - \{0\}$.

Comment: how can i show that A^1 and A^1-{0} are not isomorphic!!

Comment: I typed an answer to your previous question (why $V(y^2 - x) \cong \mathbb A^1)$, just to notice that you've changed it now. Not cool. Your current question has been answered on this site before.

Comment: I have not changed it...someone else has edited it...and i know how to show they are isomorphic pls tell me why A^1  and A^1 -{0} are not isomorphic or homeomorphic!!

Comment: No worries. The previous question was in the comments. As for your current question, just search the site. This has been asked before.

Comment: It seems I made some typing error. I meant $V(y-x^2)$.

Comment: @tandra: $\mathbb{A}^1, \mathbb{A}^1 - \{0\}$ are both affine, so they are isomorphic iff their coordinate rings ($k[x], k[x,y]/(xy-1) \cong k[x,x^{-1}]$ respectively) are isomorphic